# Problem with Epson L360 printer-

Tags: 16.04, gnome, epson

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and want to connect Epson L360 printer to the laptop. The printer is shown in the devices and printer list.
 When clicked on print test page all I get is a string of M's 2 and a // on the left side of the page. 
Any help in fixing this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the driver for the L360 can be downloaded from here; http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=34541&DSCCHK=141ba614c212ead0099d27f8dc8f2bc35faf7781

if you have 64bit Ubuntu, you need epson-inkjet-printer-201401w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

As you click to download, your system may offer to "open" the package, this should mean gdebi installer will install the package; thus install the drivers; if you save to your Downloads folder instead, you can install from there.

Best delete any existing L360 icon in your PRINTERS folder before installing the above; rationale being delete what you say is not working

Comment: glad all is good